# StrtoInt64Def convert error in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I am having small program having ConvertFunction which converts the string data to other formats. The return type of function is Variant. When i use StrToIntDef to convert integer value then it does without any error.

But now my number is very large so I want to use int64 instead of integer. When i use StrToInt64def function to convert its giving me error, Incompatiable types:Variant and int64.

Below are the both codes. Any idea whats wrong in this?

Working:

```
function Convertfunction(sTest:String):Variant;
begin
  result:= StrtoIntDef(sTest,0);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sString: string;
  value:variant;
begin
  sString:= '123456';
  value:= Convertfunction(sString);
  showMessage(value);
end;
```

Not Working:

```
function Convertfunction(sTest:String):Variant;
begin
  result:= StrtoInt64Def(sTest,0);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sString: string;
  value:variant;
begin
  sString:= '12345678901';
  value:= Convertfunction(sString);
  showMessage(value);
end;
```

Comment: Check variant type if it can contain int64 type in D5. You can search Delphi sources and help for VarType function and constants like varString. If it does not - you would have to implement int64 support for variant. Also try to introduce temporary int64 var and write your function in two lines. Probably would not change things, but sometimes compilers have strange bugs and oversights

Comment: D5 doesnt support variant type to store int64.

Comment: Then you can implement it. Or switch to CodeTyphon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delphi 5 doesn't seem to have stock converter between int64 and variant. If you need it in your app you can

- implement it (see manual on "custom variant types")
- switch to more recent Delphi
- switch to CodeTyphon or other Lazarus/FPC distro